# Impala Regex: Match String between character a and b (if b exists)

Tags: regex, impala

I am trying to write a regex using Impala to match the string between two characters where the 2nd character may not be present. For example, I want to match everything between the `@` character and the `.` (if the dot operator exists).

- test @ mytest.stackoverflow.com -> return **mytest**
- test @ mytest -> return **mytest**

I wrote the following regex and it works, but I think it could definitely be written in a cleaner way.

`regexp_extract(regexp_extract('test @ mytest.stackoverflow.com', '^([^.]*).*', 1), '@(.*?)', 1) ->` **mytest**

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following pattern, which places the text you want to match inside a capture group:

```
@([^.]*)[.]?

SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT('test @ mytest.stackoverflow.com', '@([^.]*)[.]?', 1) AS result
FROM yourTable;
```

Here is demo showing the regex by itself in action:

### Demo

Comment: This works, but it doesn't work in Impala specifically. I think Impala has some weird restrictions around regex.

Comment: @DavidZ Yes, I noticed this about Impala regex.  I will leave this answer up in case it might help someone else find the right answer.